# livewire how to use laravel controller store data concept in livewire

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

hello im new to livewire in laravel controller i used some methods to store data now livewire im totally confused how to use this concept.
below i attached my laravel controller code that working. and livewire code giving error
Attempt to read property "name" on array.

> my laravel controller code

```
 public function Store(Request $request)
 {
  $input['name'] = ucwords(strtolower($request->name));  
  $input['email'] = $request->email; 
  $input['date_of_join'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->date_of_join) );
 User::create($input);
 }
```

> livewire code

```
     public $name;
     public $email;
     public $date_of_join;

   public function submit() 
    {
     $validatedData = $this->validate([
             'name' => 'required',
             'email'        => 'required', 
             'date_of_join' => 'required',        
    ]);       

    $store = ([
        'name'          =>  ucwords(strtolower($validatedData->name)),
        'email'         =>  $validatedData->email; 
        'date_of_join'  => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($validatedData->date_of_join) );
    ]);
    User::create($store);
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you implement Livewire's own validation, read here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `validate` returns an `array`, not an `object`. Therefore, you must access it by index:

```php
$store = ([
    'name' =>  ucwords(strtolower($validatedData['name'])),
    'email' =>  $validatedData['email']; 
    'date_of_join' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($validatedData['date_of_join']));
]);
```

P.S. It's always better to use `$request->input($key)` instead of `$request->$key`. This way you prevent potential variable conflicts.